# Are bitwise rotations slower than shifts on current Intel CPU?

Tags: java, assembly, rotation, bit-shift

I was curious if `java.lang.Integer.rotateLeft` gets optimized by using a rotation instruction and wrote a benchmark for it. The results were inconclusive: It was much faster than two shifts but a bit slower than a single one. So I rewrote it in C++ and got about the same results. When compiling via `g++ -S -Wall -O3` I can see the instruction in the [generated assembler](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RotationBenchmark.s). My CPU is Intel Core i5.

The [benchmark](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RotationBenchmark.cc) is quite long and surely not the nicest piece of code, but I don't think it's broken. Or is it? According to the documentation the rotations take one cycle, just like shifts. Can anybody explain the results?

```
rotations:  6860
shift:      5100
```

---

The first two answers are wrong. Both gcc and java's JIT know the rotation instructions and use them. Concerning gcc see the link above, concerning java see my [java benchmark](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/MgLongRotationBenchmark.java) and its results

```
benchmark   ns linear runtime
   Rotate 3.48 ====================
NonRotate 5.05 ==============================
    Shift 2.16 ============
```

Comment: @maartinus: I've deleted my answer, thanks for the correction

Comment: Ok, first, your question does not match it's description. You asking about shift and rotate instructions of the CPU and then you try to find out how some particular compilers are clever enough to use it or not. All of `rol` and `sar` and `shl` are executed in the same amount of CPU clocks for a very long time. I remove my answer as the question is not well defined.

Comment: @Serge: I'll look if I can improve the wording. I described how I found out that the compilers do optimize using `rol` and `ror` and than I asked if anybody can explain the results, as (in contradiction to your comment) *rotations take longer than shifts*.

Comment: FYI. Rotations **are not taking longer** than shifts on Intel CPU since 8086/8088.

Comment: @Serge: Sure, that's what I've also read. But according to the benchmark they are.

Comment: Your benchmark is incorrect to consider if we are speaking about a time the CPU spend for a single rotate or shift instruction. Regarding your java benchmark. It is JIT implementation behavior. Nothing else. Does the JIT folds the code I used to cite into single `rol` instruction? Doubtfully.

Comment: @Serge: You're wrong again. I've never said I'm trying to measure the speed of a single instruction. Instead my benchmarks show that the timing of rotate and shift differ, and the difference was significant. I intermixed other operations 1. in order to make it more realistic (nothing can be computed by using only rotations), 2.  in order for the JIT not to optimize the whole computation away. The new answers shows another benchmark *confirming my results* and also a *very good explanation* for what's actually happening here.

Comment: "Are bitwise rotations slower than shifts on current Intel CPU?" is it a caption of your question or I missed something?

Comment: Indeed, it's the caption, and it's exactly what my benchmarks are about. And the answer is: both are 1-cycle ops, but rotation has lower throughput.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not know that gcc and the java jit were capable of recognizing that a sequence of SHIFT and OR operators can be reduced to a ROTATE instruction, very interesting.

The g++ compiler unrolls your loops and uses `SHIFT immediate` and `ROTATE immediate` instructions (since you shift and rotate by constant values).

Here's the six instruction sequence that is repeated in the TimeShift loop unroll case:

```
movq    %rax, %rbx
salq    $13, %rbx
leaq    (%rbp,%rbx), %rbx
movq    %rdi, %rbp
sarq    $27, %rbp
xorq    %rbx, %rdx
```

Here's the six instruction sequence that is repeated in the TimeRotate loop unroll case:

```
movq    %rdx, %rbx
rorq    $45, %rbx
leaq    (%rbp,%rbx), %rbx
movq    %r8, %rbp
rorq    $49, %rbp
xorq    %rbx, %r9
```

They differ mainly in the use of salq/sarq for `SHIFT` and rorq for `ROTATE` so you are correct in wondering why the timing differs.

The answer lies deep in the micro-architecture of Sandy Bridge (your Core i5 processor) and is found in [INTEL® 64 and IA-32 Processor Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf)
The latest is `Order Number: 248966-026 April 2012`

The `SHIFT` instruction has 1 cycle latency whether you use the `by 1` opcode or `by immediate`.  It can dispatch from either `Port 0` or `Port 1` and for this reason has a 0.5 cycle throughput - the processor can dispatch and retire two `SHIFT immediate` instructions per cycle.  The `ROTATE` instruction needs three micro-ops if the results of the condition flags are needed (they aren't in the code generated by gcc) and two micro-ops if not (so two micro-ops in your case).  The `ROTATE` instruction, however, can only be dispatched from `Port 1` and therefore has a 1 cycle throughput - the processor can dispatch and retire only one `ROTATE immediate` per cycle.

I've copied the relevant image and section below.

**3.5.1.5  Bitwise Rotation**

Bitwise rotation can choose between rotate with count specified in the CL register, an 
immediate constant and by 1 bit. Generally, The rotate by immediate and rotate by 
register instructions are slower than rotate by 1 bit. The rotate by 1 instruction has 
the same latency as a shift.
*Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 35. (ML impact, L generality) Avoid ROTATE 
by register or ROTATE by immediate instructions. If possible, replace with a 
ROTATE by 1 instruction.*
In Intel microarchitecture code name Sandy Bridge, ROL/ROR by immediate has 1-
cycle throughput, SHLD/SHRD using the same register as source and destination by 
an immediate constant has 1-cycle latency with 0.5 cycle throughput. The “ROL/ROR 
reg, imm8” instruction has two micro-ops with the latency of 1-cycle for the rotate 
register result and 2-cycles for the flags, if used.
In Intel microarchitecture code name Ivy Bridge, The “ROL/ROR reg, imm8” instruction with immediate greater than 1, is one micro-op with one-cycle latency when the 
overflow flag result is used. When the immediate is one, dependency on the overflow 
flag result of ROL/ROR by a subsequent instruction will see the ROL/ROR instruction 
with two-cycle latency.

**2.4.4.2  Execution Units and Issue Ports**

At each cycle, the core may dispatch µops to one or more of four issue ports. At the 
microarchitecture level, store operations are further divided into two parts: store 
data and store address operations. The four ports through which μops are dispatched 
to execution units and to load and store operations are shown in Figure 2-6. Some 
ports can dispatch two µops per clock. Those execution units are marked Double 
Speed.

**Port 0.** In the first half of the cycle, port 0 can dispatch either one floating-point 
move µop (a floating-point stack move, floating-point exchange or floating-point 
store data) or one arithmetic logical unit (ALU) µop (arithmetic, logic, branch or store 
data). In the second half of the cycle, it can dispatch one similar ALU µop.

**Port 1.** In the first half of the cycle, port 1 can dispatch either one floating-point 
execution (all floating-point operations except moves, all SIMD operations) µop or 
one normal-speed integer (multiply, shift and rotate) µop or one ALU (arithmetic) 
µop. In the second half of the cycle, it can dispatch one similar ALU µop.

**Port 2.** This port supports the dispatch of one load operation per cycle.

**Port 3.** This port supports the dispatch of one store address operation per cycle.

The total issue bandwidth can range from zero to six µops per cycle. Each pipeline 
contains several execution units. The µops are dispatched to the pipeline that corresponds to the correct type of operation. For example, an integer arithmetic logic unit 
and the floating-point execution units (adder, multiplier, and divider) can share a 
pipeline.

[image: Figure 2-11. Execution Units and Ports in Out-Of-Order Core]

Comment: Completely rewrote my answer to provide what I believe is the correct explanation for the timing difference.

Comment: Perfect work! I was searching in the doc you linked but couldn't find it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did a search (Command-F on my Mac) on that PDF document and found 18 references to `rotate`, that's how I found it.

Comment: I did the same, but somehow managed to miss it (probably I was too sleepy). :D

Answer (score 5):

According to this [benchmark](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel0020652_Clarkdale_InstLatX86.txt), the shifts and rotate both have the same latency on your CPU, but rotates have a lower throughput (results listed there as "T" are reciprocal throughput, which is more easily comparable with latencies). That could have precisely the kind of result you're seeing - the lower throughput sort of gets in the way a little, but you weren't completely saturating the execution units so it doesn't show the full factor of 2 difference. Testing that yourself is *not easy*, especially not if you have to fight a compiler to make it emit the instructions your want.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I computed (from this and some similar benchmarks) the difference as being less than 1 cycle, which I found quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking at micro-benchmarks, you have to consider that the JIT will optimise common patterns e.g. shift, it recognises more efficiently than uncommon patterns e.g. rotate (or ones it does not recognise)  This can means that two operations which should take the same amount of time can perform quite differently because one is more heavily optimised than the other. e.g. with more loop unrolling or dead code removal.

Even simple instructions can interact to produce different and unexpected results. In other words you cannot look at a single instruction and assume it tell you very much about how it will perform when more instructions are used. Context is important at such a low level.

I suggest you try comparing these operations in a realistic program and I suspect you will have great difficulty finding a measurable difference.

Comment: You've made a good point with common pattern in JIT and maybe gcc "gets tired" by optimizing into rotations as well, and this could be the explanation. I'll try with some assembler.

Comment: But I disagree w.r.t. the realistic program -- a realistic program either uses no rotations at all or it's something like [RC5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) and than it matters a lot; just like in my benchmark.