# What is the most performant/correct way of doing a bit shift & mask?

Tags: c++

I've seen two different ways to approach combining bit shifting and masking, and was wondering if they were equivalent assuming the result is used as a boolean or if one had less issues or better performance than the other.

The two:

`flags & (BIT_MASK << BIT_NUMBER)`

or

`(flags >> BIT_NUMBER) & BIT_MASK`

The former seems like it might have issues on some platforms depending on the size of `flags`, i.e. the bit shift might push the mask out the top of the temporary variable.  Is this an issue?  Are there any performance differences in up-shifting versus down-shifting?

Combining `BIT_MASK` and `BIT_NUMBER` into a single unambiguous mask strikes me as better again, but I'm working with legacy code that I want to minimize changes to.

Comment: Overflow issues aside, they're not functionally equivalent (unless the result is used a boolean).

Comment: Good catch - yes, I'm using the result as a boolean.  Edited that in.

Comment: I am pretty sure both alternatives uses two instruction, so they are the same.

Comment: Can someone tell me what I am missing, what the hell does it matter whether the first or second option?

Comment: See the answers.  The first results in fewer instructions.  All other things being equal, that should be the preferred option - similar to using ++i versus i++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `BIT_MASK` and `BIT_NUMBER` are constants, the compiler will probably precalculate the expression and save an instruction if you group them together. This favors the first approach.

If you're trying to get more than one bit you will want to shift the result to the right. This favors the second approach.

Comment: I don't think there's any "probably" about it. Given an arithmetic operation on two constant values, even in debug mode, the compiler will calculate the result at compile time. Many parts of the language require this. (e.g. `const int X = 1 + 1;` must not cause code to execute at runtime)

Comment: Why does getting more than one bit favour the second?

Comment: @dlanod, because you probably want to evaluate the result as a number rather than a boolean.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, I agree that you're unlikely to find a compiler that doesn't optimize constant expressions, but is it really required by the standard?

Comment: Yes, things like an `enum` are required by the standard to take constant expressions and generate no code. Or obviously template instantiation. There are lots of cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom Inevitably I ask about multiple bits and six hours later find that I fall afoul of exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

`flags & (BIT_MASK << BIT_NUMBER)` can be done in one bit-and instruction.

`(flags >> BIT_NUMBER) & BIT_MASK` requires two instructions, a shift followed by a bit-and.

(Actually, on PowerPC, the second version also has a dedicated opcode, `rlwinm`, but Intel doesn't have such luck.)

The biggest difference, of course, is that they generate different result values. If you're only checking for zero or non-zero, then I'd prefer the first version as it's a single instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't think in terms of what the compiler back-end might do, if you are not using optimization then it doesn't matter and if you are using optimization then any good compiler will do the right thing in as few instructions as possible for your compilation target.

Think in terms of what it means semantically in the language.  For example, if flags is of type `uint64_t` and `BIT_NUMBER` is greater than 31 then only the 2nd form will likely do what you intend.  The reason is that `(BIT_MASK << BIT_NUMBER)` will be evaluated as an `int`, likely 32-bits, and since `BIT_NUMBER` is greater than 31 that will evaluate to zero so the whole thing will yield zero after the AND.  On the other hand `(flags >> BIT_NUMBER)` will be evaluated as a 64-bit expression (because flags is 64-bits) and will be properly shifted before doing the AND.

For an interesting talk about the Clang compiler see [Clang: Defending C++ from Murphy's Million Monkeys](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Clang-Defending-C-from-Murphy-s-Million-Monkeys) this will show you the depths of semantic understanding possible in today's compilers, in particular look at minute `21:25` which addresses the nuances of C++ integer arithmetic rules that I refer to above.  This is the example used in the talk

```
static const long long DiskCacheSize = 8 << 30; // 8 Gigs

Clang gives:

% clang++ -std=c++11 -fsyntax-only overflow.cpp
overflow.cpp:1:42: warning: signed shift result (0x200000000) requires 35 
bits to represent, but 'int' only has 32 bits [-Wshift-overflow]
static const long long DiskCacheSize = 8 << 30; // 8 Gigs
                                       ~ ^  ~~
```

Recently I was surprised to learn that gcc and Java JIT compilers are smart enough to understand that a group of shifts, masks, and ORs are essentially doing a rotate of a 32-bit quantity, for example, and will generate a rotate instruction, see [Are bitwise rotations slower than shifts on current Intel CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770667/are-bitwise-rotations-slower-than-shifts-on-current-intel-cpu).  Compilers are very good these days.