# What is the cost of Java's native methods?

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface

Recently, when I was reading some article (do not ask me to remember it's title), I found out that improving performance with Java's `native` methods is not such a good idea, as switching state of thread, converting Java's variables and classes into C's variables and other necessary operations do also take some time to execute method.

But, what it the exact time per variable conversation and wouldn't it be better to use `ProcessBuilder`?

Which is faster:

```java
try{
    new ProcessBuilder("pseudo-method name","and","other","parameters").start();
}catch(IOEcxeption ex){}
```

or

```java
nativeMethod();
```

?
And what is the precise time of executing them (considering application and method are both empty)?

Comment: I don't know how it compares in performance, but these two are totally different things. The first executes a stand-alone native program in a separate operating system process, while the second executes a linked native function in the same process.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @k314159, So is separate process always slower?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699020/what-makes-jni-calls-slow/7809300#7809300

Comment: Hm ... if only there was some site that has a collection and questions and answers to the kinds of questions you post as a comment here. If only such a site had a search bar on top ...

Comment: [*JEP 454: Foreign Function & Memory API*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/454)

Comment: Your phrase “converting Java's variables and classes into C's variables” indicates that you are assuming that a `native` method has to be implemented in C. This is not the case. A method declared `native` is not implemented in ordinary Java code, that’s all you know about the method for sure. Since this does not mandate any way to implement it, no statement about the performance can be made. And, as others already said, creating a new process is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Ok... should I delete my question now?

Comment: If you have to choose between offloading something to a separate process called by process builder, and a native method that does the exact same thing, then I'm pretty sure that in most cases, calling that native method will perform better than launching a separate process through process builder. Possible performance issues with native methods may happen when you have a lot of very short-lived native method calls. On the other hand, if you have a method call which does a lot of work in one call, the overhead of the native call itself is negligible compared to the actual work.

Comment: Thanks everyone why tried to answer it.

Comment: *I found out that improving performance with Java's native methods is not such a good idea* The JVM itself uses native [intrinsic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698783/what-is-the-difference-between-java-intrinsic-and-native-methods) for CPU intensive tasks. Try this:  get the source code for one of Java's cryptographic functions out of the OpenJDK source code.  Refactor it so you can compile and run it as normal Java code and then benchmark it against the JVM's implementation, which uses intrinsics. Pure Java will be lucky to get within an order of magnitude of the native.